# EPPlus: Locale settings in cell value and formula

Tags: c#, excel, localization, epplus

I want to export formulas from a C# application to an Excel Sheet using the EPPlus library.

The locale settings of the C# application as well as the Excel Application are identical, which means that the decimal separator is a comma in my case.

While the assignment

`sheet.Cells[row, column].Value = value;`

will correctly be used by Excel (for example if value is a double),

the same will not work with

`sheet.Cells[row, column].Formula = formula;`

where formula is a string beginning with "=" and containing string converted doubles correctly containing a comma as a decimal separator.

In the latter case, Excel will say that the document is broken, while it will accept formulas containing a dot as a decimal separator.

I do not want to start replacing commas with dots or vice versa, but keeping the correct locale chain into the Excel formula.

Can this be done somehow? I think I need a setting through EPPlus to tell Excel that the locale setting in the formula is the same as in the normal cell content (where everything works as expected).

Answer (score 0):

The localization option available in EPPlus is NumberFormat property to set your desired number format.

In your case, you could try:

```
sheet.Cells[row, column].Numberformat.Format="#,##0.00"; //set your format of dots & commas
```